# OpenNaaS build error on mvn install

Tags: maven, opennaas

When I try to build OpenNaaS project, directly download from Github, I'm getting the following error in `mvn install`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project org.opennaas.core.resources: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.opennaas:org.opennaas.core.resources:bundle:0.29-SNAPSHOT:...   [ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.opennaas.core.resources
```

I'm newbie in OpenNaaS and also in Maven. My environment is Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits whit Maven 3 version. I have not any changes in `src` or other files in OpenNaaS stable project that I have downloaded. How I can build this project?

Comment: please, provide the Java version, including the vendor (is it official Oracle one?)

Comment: one more thing, could you post the entire error log? it is necessary to know the origin of the issue. from what I see, you are building an snapshot version. try to checkout `master` branch with: `git checkout master` and try to build it again with `mvn clean install` (by default OpenNaaS GitHub repository clones `develop` branch, that is not stable at all).